# How to get InnerText and InnerXml of a Node from XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmldocument, xmlnode

For example, I have this xml string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
   <text>How to get <bold>all</bold> this string's content?</text>
</data>
```

I want to get all these elements in an array of objects (for each object I have a class), without loosing their structure:

```
[1] (TextClass; where bold = false) How to get 
[2] (TextClass; where bold = true) all
[3] (TextClass; where bold = false) this string's content?
```

All I'm getting using `XmlDocument` and `XmlNode` classes right now is InnerText Or InnerXml separately.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("example.xml");
foreach (XmlNode child in xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
{
   string chName = child.Name; // text
   string text = child.InnerText; // How to get all this string's content?
   string xml = child.InnerXml; // How to get <bold>all</bold>this string's content?
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: What are you actually asking here? You've got the children. What are you missing? Iterate through `ChildNodes` and create your own class instances accordingly. Add them to a `List<T>` or whatever. Or use LINQ.

Comment: @EdPlunkett What I'm trying to archieve is that I want to get the sequence of text, in which I will may  have a XmlNode, which indicates that this text is stylized. By iterating throw child nodes I will lose this sequence, because I will get the text and stylized text separately of each other.

Comment: What sequence of text? What's wrong with the one you have? Can you show me an example of a sequence of child nodes that appears out of order in `ChildNodes`? What do you mean "separately of each other"?

Comment: Oh wait a minute, you're looking at the children of the document root. You need the children of the "data" node. Put that code in a recursive function. If `child.ChildNodes.Count > 0`, recurse.

Comment: Or just xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//data") and iterate through his children.

Comment: I misspoke -- you're looking at "data"'s children; you want those of "text". @Kennet has a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of work I think it is easier to use the [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693228.aspx).

In your example something like the following could work (depending on exactly what you want to achieve):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var textClasses = from n in doc.Descendants("text").DescendantNodes()
                  where n.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text
                  select new { text = ((XText)n).Value, bold = n.Parent?.Name == "bold" };
```

And a [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SGxkAS) so you can quickly see the result.